# How to convert dynamic json into a custom string?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, converters

I need to convert json to a useful string like this:

```
    COLUMN1:DATA1;COLUMN2:DATA2;............. 
    COLUMN1:DATA3;COLUMN2:DATA4;.............
    ..............................
```

I can't use a static class where I put these data, because the columnsname, workspacesname etc. are always different.
I found the json framework but didn't come along with this.
If some would be so nice and can put in here a little sample, I would be happy.

Thanks Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also find that [DynamicJson](http://dynamicjson.codeplex.com/) is a very good solution for this. It will also work if everything is dynamic (yes, also the keys...)

Here is an example of the DynamicJson Page:

```
// DynamicJson - (IsObject)
var objectJson = DynamicJson.Parse(@"{""foo"":""json"",""bar"":100}");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> item in objectJson)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ":" + item.Value); // foo:json, bar:100
}
```

I think this example is exactly what you need. Good Luck. (It will also work with nested objects/arrays)